# Is there a way to get the class Name from where I create an instance of another class by importing it?

Tags: python

Given:

```
Module A.py
    class utilities:
        
        def __init__(self):
            #Is there a way to get the class that instantiates this constructor ? But here, in the init method?
            
        def utilMethod(self):
            pass


Module B.py
from A import utilities

    class dummy:
    
        utils = utilities()
        
        def dummyMthod(self):
            utils.utilMethod()
```

#Is there a way to get the class that instantiates utilities class constructor ? But in the init method of the class being instanciated?

Comment: The only thing I know of that might give you this information is a stack trace.  You should be able to obtain a stack trace for where you currently are, and with it, get information about the caller of the method you are in.  Check out the standard `traceback` module.

Comment: `__init__():` does not take the `self` parameter?

Comment: It does now, edited it, mybad

Comment: How is the second part (`Module B.py`) relevant? You say you only care in the `__init__` method.

Comment: Its just an example, that describes in which way i intend to use class utilities, and from where i'd like to instanciate it, which will result in the expected outcome of my request which should be the "dummy" class name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're instantiating `utils` as a static variable, at the time of its creation class dummy is not yet available so the answer is "no": you can't do that.

Alternative solution: "pass yourself in" (see code comments for explanations)

```
class utilities:

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def utilMethod(self, obj):  # the caller is passed in
        print(obj.__class__.__name__) # this is how we can access the class-name of the caller
        pass

class dummy:
    utils = utilities()

    def dummyMthod(self):
        self.utils.utilMethod(self) # here we "pass ourselves in"


d = dummy()
d.dummyMthod() # prints "dummy"
```

**UPDATE**

If we want to declare `utils` as an object attribute (vs. static class attribute in the previous snippet), we can do:

```
class utilities:

    def __init__(self, obj):
        print(obj.__class__.__name__)
        pass

    def utilMethod(self, obj):
        pass

class dummy:

    def __init__(self):
        self.utils = utilities(self) # declare utils as object attribute inside the constructor and pass 'self' into utilities

    def dummyMthod(self):
        self.utils.utilMethod()


d = dummy() # prints "dummy"
```

Comment: Well no, `utils` is a class attribute defined outside of the constructor, its not static at all, while the solution is clever, I don't want to call utilMethod inside `dummyMethod`, will it help if utils was declared inside the constructor itself?

Comment: @Rolfsky per a few different sources such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68672/1057429) that's how you declare a static class variable, but of course I may be mistaken or using the wrong term. As for your followup question: if I understand correctly I think that the answer is "yes": if you declare `utils` as an object attribute (inside dummy's ctor), e.g.: `self.utils = utilities(self)` you should be able to use this exact same solution only by having `obj` passed as a constructor argument into `utilities` constructor

Comment: Yup, thinking if there's any other way, done it with traceback aswell, but that's just ugly regex, update indeed, does what is required, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Within `__init__` (and generally within the methods of the class) you can use `self.__class__` and/or `self.__class__.__name__`; the latter can be particularly useful for logging and similar messages.

```
self.logger = logging.getLogger(self.__class__.__name__)
```

(Or similar, perhaps also incorporating the module name.)

Comment: By calling `self.__class__.__name__`  you'll get `"utilities"` not `"dummy"` as a result

Comment: Ah, I've misread the question. You can get that through the `inspect` module, in particular `inspect.currentframe()` and/or `inspect.stack()`.